# Web Serial API - Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to open serial port / required member baudRate is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webapi, webusb, serialapi

The code below works on my Xubuntu machine, but now I'm on Kubuntu and it isn't working anymore - it won't open the port.

The Arduino IDE works fine (can write code to the board) and I'm able to select the device (Arduino Uno) in Chrome, but the code will stop when I try to open the port: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to open serial port` or `required member baudRate is undefined` will come up.

```
const filters = [
  // Filter on devices with the Arduino Uno USB Vendor/Product IDs.
  { usbVendorId: 0x2341, usbProductId: 0x0043 },
  { usbVendorId: 0x2341, usbProductId: 0x0001 },
];

  async function getPortAndStartReading() {
    if (!portFound) {
      const port = await navigator.serial.requestPort({ filters });
      await port.open({ baudRate: 9600 }) //problem here
      reader = port.readable.getReader();
      outputStream = port.writable
      readLoop();
      if (port) {
          connectionToPortSuccessfulMessage = 'Connection successful'
          setPortFound(true)
      }
    }
  }
```

I've tried changing the permissions on the serial port by following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58119/changing-permissions-on-serial-port), so now if I run `groups user` I get `user : user adm dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare`, but it still won't work.

I've also checked `chrome://device-log` to see if I could find any errors but all I get is info about (physically) adding or removing a USB device.

Comment: I'm having the same issue in Windows, but not on OSX.

Comment: In the device log, if you plugin and unplug your device, do you see: `Serial->Event: Serial Device Added path=COM3, etc` and `USB->USER: USB Device added, etc` and similar for removed? If I log the output of `port.getSignals`, that's where I'm seeing a Promise with State of "rejected" and Result of "DOMException: The device has been lost"

Comment: Also, for me, initial connection works, but subsequent connections produce the error.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the member name has recently been changed from 'baudrate' to 'baudRate'. At least in my case changing from 'baudrate' (which used to work) to 'baudRate' fixed it for me. Could it perhaps be Kubuntu is using an older chrome version that expects 'baudrate'.

Comment: This fixed it for me! Thanks! I'm worried now about what else has changed.